# How to wrap paragraph inside a `tabular*`?

Tags: tables, xetex, article

This is a section of the LaTeX document I'm working on.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{nopageno}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\setmainfont{Lato Regular}

\begin{document}
    \subsubsection*{\underline{CONTRIBUTIONS}}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt, label={}]
        \item{
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
                \textbf{\href{https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs}{nixpkgs ->}}
                &\textbf{Nix}\\
            \end{tabular*}
        }
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

It looks something like this:
[image: without the paragraph]

I have come with a way to wrap text:

```latex
...
\begin{document}
    \subsubsection*{\underline{CONTRIBUTIONS}}
    \begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt, label={}]
        \item{
            \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}r}
                \textbf{\href{https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs}{nixpkgs ->}}
                &\textbf{Nix}\\
                \multicolumn{2}{c}{\parbox{\linewidth}{Nixpkgs is a collection of over 80,000 software packages that can be installed with the Nix package manager. It also implements NixOS, a purely-functional Linux distribution.}}
            \end{tabular*}
        }
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This is how it looks like:
[image: my solution]

Is there a better way to do the same? I feel like I'm adding to the complexity here.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Off-topic: `\item` does *not* take an argument enclosed in curly braces. Writing `\item{...}` instead of `\item ...` is an example of pointless code clutter.

Comment: @Mico I use it because it is really fast to jump between brackets while using a modal editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a better way to do the same?

I suggest using `\multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{...}` for the passage in question. I would also set `\tabcolsep` to 0pt; if you don't set `\tabcolsep` to 0pt, you'll need to write `\multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}}{...}`. A separate advantage of setting `\tabcolsep` to 0pt is that the table's left-hand edge will be aligned perfectly with the left-hand edge of the subsubsection-level header.

Why not pursue the `\parbox` approach, you may ask? I'd say that since we're inside a `tabular*` structure, which gives access to the `p` column type, there's no need to incur the overhead incurred by `\parbox`.

Separately, the `itemize` machinery seems to be set up to do nothing at all -- cf. `leftmargin=0pt, label={}` -- and should therefore be omitted or, at the very least, be commented out.

Finally, I think that `\href{https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs}{\textbf{nixpkgs ->}}` is more idiomatic than `\textbf{\href{https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs}{nixpkgs ->}}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.25in, noheadfoot, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Lato}

% packages not needed for this example:
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{nopageno}
%\usepackage{tabularx}   

\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{\underline{CONTRIBUTIONS}}

%%%%\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=0pt, label={}]
%%%%\item 
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % <-- new
\noindent % <-- new
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lr }
   \href{https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs}{\textbf{nixpkgs ->}}
   &\textbf{Nix}\\
   \multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{Nixpkgs is a collection of 
     over 80,000 software packages that can be installed with 
     the Nix package manager. It also implements NixOS, a 
     purely-functional Linux distribution.}
\end{tabular*}

%%%%\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: About the only difference between `p` and `\parbox` are the optional] arguments, whereas tabular uses `\def\@startpbox#1{\vtop\bgroup \setlength\hsize{#1}\@arrayparboxrestore}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo - Thanks! I realize that I didn't express myself well at all. What I was thinking about -- and should have stated explicitly -- is that `\multicolumn{2}{p{\linewidth}}{...}` is marginally simpler to write down than the OP's `\multicolumn{2}{c}{\parbox{\linewidth}{...}}`.

Comment: @Mico thank you for sharing this: `\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}` and `\noindent`. This has fixed most of the issues with text overflow.

Comment: About the `\items`, actually there's a bunch of other stuff I had to add to create a list-like entity for my resume. I've read that `\documentclass{article}` should be avoided, and perhaps I might need to explore alternative document formats. And as you've said, `\parbox` is really helpful in my situation.